# C++ Able to open a file in Code::Blocks with its full path, but not with relative path as a command line argument

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am working on a C++ homework project in Code::Blocks where the file name to open is specified in the first command line argument.  The file I am trying to open is titled InputFile1.txt.  When I run the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::cerr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     ifstream inputFile;

     puts(getcwd(0,1234));

     inputFile.open(argv[1]);
     if (inputFile.is_open())
     {
         cerr << "Couldn't open file " << argv[1];
         return(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     cout << "\nThe file to search is: " << argv[1];

     return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The error message "Couldn't open file InputFile1.txt" is displayed.  However when I type in the full path to InputFile1.txt the file successfully opens as indicated by the output of the message on the bottom.  The following troubleshooting steps have been taken:

1. Successfully opened the file with a C program running on the same IDE.
2. Verified the file name was correctly spelt and was the first command line argument; also opened the file with gedit.
3. Verified the file path matched the current working directory output by the puts(getcwd(0,1234) statement.
4. Verified the Code::Blocks project execution working directory (Projects > Properties > Build targets - Execution working dir:) matched the output of step 3, and that InputFile1.txt was in the working directory.
5. Changed the working directory to a directory one level up and copied InputFile1.txt to the directory.  Once again, success with the full path but not as argv[1].

My analysis:

- I don't think it is file permissions or else it wouldn't open in gedit or with the full path.
- I don't think it is the Execution working directory or it wouldn't have opened for the C program run inside of Code::Blocks.
- It is something to do with my C++ code or Code::Blocks configuration.

Any insights/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your IDE probably does not have the same working directory as your application is in and invokes your application with a relative path eg. `debug32\my_app.exe`; therefore the relative path to any files may will be different (relative paths are relative to the working directory not the application directory).  Does your application work correctly when run from the command line (outside of the IDE)?  Also try printing `argv[0]` to check how your application was invoked.

Comment: I forgot to mention that during my troubleshooting I read a post on stack overflow about the Code::Blocks Project Bin & Obj directories, and tried to brute force a solution by moving a copy into the respective directories and opening the file.  No success.

Comment: Richard - Thanks for your help!  Will definitely keep your advice in mind next time I have issues opening a file in Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code listed above was working correctly.  The if statement in the code below:

```
 inputFile.open(argv[1]);
 if (inputFile.is_open())
 {
     cerr << "Couldn't open file " << argv[1];
     return(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

was evaluating the result of the expression `inputFile.is_open()`, which returned true when the file was successfully opened.  To check if the file had not been successfully opened, the expression `!inputFile.is_open()` should have been used.  Thanks to my prof for helping me resolve this issue - the error was all my own.